# How to parse RSS File with Azure Mobile Services Scheduler

Tags: node.js, mobile, azure, windows-mobile, azure-mobile-services

Good Morning,
I'd like to parse an RSS Feed by Azure Mobile Services Scheduler (Server Script). I should like to run an server script which consume an RSS Feed an insert results to Azure Database. But ... I can't find any example for this.

Can someone help me? Any examples or experience?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry. I forget to say, i have an xml file response from RSS. Not an JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team has plans to add some node modules which deal with XML data in the near future to the Azure Mobile Service runtime. Once those modules are in place, you should be able to `require` them and treat the incoming XML data easier. I'll try to update this answer once that feature goes into production.

Answer (score 1):

this sample parses a feed from nuget: [Send Push Notifications at Periodic Interval with the Mobile Services Scheduler](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Send-Push-Notifications-at-cd0ccd48)

Comment: Thanks. now, i have result as xml. therefore i can`t parse in json. i think it can be a problem with the source rss link?